# Не могу отправить detail в destinationViewController

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Я хочу отправить detail в destinationViewController.

```
[segue.destinationViewController setDetail:item];
```

http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2014-05/17/x2pu26iznie1.png

Но я получаю ошибку:

http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2014-05/17/obg25xfg6be6.png

Как мне исправить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты пытаешься отправить detail в UINavigationController, а нужно отправлять в ModalKillerViewController:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];
ModalKillerViewController *modalKiller = (ModalKillerViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
[modalKiller setDetail:item];
```

Как-то так.